# How would integrate $\frac 32e^{-x^2}$ without Gauss error function?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, indefinite-integrals

I am going through my grade 12 textbook in the calculus section and I was asked to integrate this question:
$$ \int_0^1  \frac 32 e^{-x^2}$$

I am in grade 12 and all the answers I find online require me to use the Gauss error function. I was wondering if there is another way of doing this. Thank you for your answers and sorry if this is a hopeless question.

Comment: If there was a way, why would we need the error function? (Unless, of course, this is a definite integral: the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$ can be evaluated explicitly without the need to introduce special functions.)

Comment: You could expand as a power series and integate term-by-term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through power series, we will get:

$$e^{-x^2}= \displaystyle\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{n!}$$
Then, integrate term-by-term:

$$ \frac{3}{2}\cdot\displaystyle\int_0^1 \displaystyle\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{n!} dx $$

$$ \frac{3}{2}\cdot \displaystyle\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \displaystyle\int_0^1 x^{2n} dx $$

Which is the following convergent series

$$ \frac{3}{2}\cdot \displaystyle\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)} $$

Comment: I'm sorry but why do we want to integrate term by term? Also, why do we use Power series?

Comment: Well, $e^x$ can be express by this power series and we can integrate term-by-term since the summation can be rewriten as lots of sums and integration is linear, therefore you can integrate term-by-term.